# Sort group count results in gremlin

Tags: gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I have a list of products and order numbers, and I am using gremlin to find products associated to one specific product (let's say product 2).

I am able to query all associated products with their number of occurence. I would like to sort the results descending by the number of times an associated product occurs. At the moment, my query returns an unordered list:

```
g.V().has('PRODUCT', 'id', '2').as('a').in('purchased').out('purchased').where(neq('a')).groupCount()
```

returns:

```
==>[4:3,6:2,1:1,3:1,5:1,7:2,8:1,9:1,10:1,11:1,12:2,13:2,14:2,15:2,28:1,16:1,17:1]
```

Does anyone know how to sort the list by descending values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `order` step:

```
g.V().has('PRODUCT', 'id','2').as('a')
    .in('purchased').out('purchased')
    .where(neq('a')).groupCount()
    .order(local).by(select(values), desc)
```

**Note:** if using gremlin in version lower then 3.3.4 you may need to replace `desc` to `decr`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I figured out a similar way to do it with the order step. I have one more question: Do you know how I would get, let's say, only the first 5 results of that query? Because right now, it is returning a single array with all the results, so the limit or range steps do not work.